HTTP Request works in Postman and curl, but not in .NET Core code and throws 504 (Gateway Timeout) and 502 (Proxy Error) errors
I'm trying to call an API in my .NET Core web app project but it returns these errors as a response:

504 Gateway Timeout
502 Bad Gateway

Although, this API responds correctly using Postman and  CURL.
I investigated all the headers of Postman and  CURL in Fiddler and async them in my code, tried different HTTP Client Libraries like 'RestSharp' and 'HttpClient', even tested a simplified code in a raw .NET Core console application, ran the code on two different local machines.
public static async Task GetQuote()
{
    try
    {
        var content = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?><job><job_action>QUOTE</job_action></job>";

        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            handler.Proxy = null; // Explicitly set proxy to null
            handler.UseProxy = false; // Ensure proxy is disabled
            handler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12; // Ensure correct SSL/TLS protocol

            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); // Increase timeout duration
                // Additional Headers to match POSTMAN request
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("br"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Add("keep-alive");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                {
                    NoCache = true
                };

                var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                var byteArray = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(content);
                var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(byteArray);
                byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml");

                form.Add(byteContent, "jobxml", "job_quote.xml");

                var response = await client.PostAsync("https://www.apiServer.com/online/getxmljob.cl", form);
                Console.WriteLine("Response Status Code: " + response.StatusCode);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Response Body: " + responseBody);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"HttpRequestException: {ex.Message}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Status Code: {ex.StatusCode}");
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TaskCanceledException: Request timed out.");
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

I did everything I knew but I'm still encountering a '504 Gateway Timeout' error.
Unfortunately, the API server isn't under my control and I can't check the server-side logs for more detailed error information.
Is there anything that I can check and I haven't done it yet?
Any Clues and thoughts can save me.

There's nothing wrong with the libraries. We can't guess how you used curl and therefore what headers or options were used. The code has several issues though. handler.SslProtocols =  doesn't ensure the correct protocol is used, it prevents the use of better protocols like TLS 1.3. That's a bug. Compression is specified at the handler level. Setting the header doesn't mean HttpClient can handle compressed responses. Instead of manual encoding and serialization you could have used a StringContent with the correct encoding attribute.

Are you sure you need a FORM POST? That's usually only meant for form submissions. APIs work with just POST. SOAP definitely doesn't use FORM encoding.

I changed my code to this and it works correctly without any errors:
public static async Task GetQuote()
{
    try
    {
        var content = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?><job><job_action>QUOTE</job_action></job>";
        string boundary = "------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.apiServer.com/online/getxmljob.cl");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream);
            writer.WriteLine("--" + boundary);
            writer.WriteLine($"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"jobxml\"; filename=\"file.xml\"");
            writer.WriteLine("Content-Type: application/xml");
            writer.WriteLine();
            writer.WriteLine(content);
            writer.WriteLine("--" + boundary + "--");
            writer.Flush();
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Response Status Code: " + response.StatusCode);
            using (var responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string responseBody = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine("Response Body: " + responseBody);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"HttpRequestException: {ex.Message}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Status Code: {ex.StatusCode}");
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TaskCanceledException: Request timed out.");
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
    }
}


Not really, and what you changed isn't what you assume. HttpClient isn't broken and in fact, if you use .NET Core (which includes .NET 5 and later) HttpWebRequest is nothing more than a compatibility wrapper over a static HttpClient. What you really changes is removing the bad Accept-Encoding headers. Just adding those headers doesn't enable compression.
